# www is not working from the url in

Tags: web

MY domain is example.in and I want to use www.example.in using .htaccess file I have taken windows hosting . here is my code in .htaccess file
MY domain is exapme.in and I want to use www.example.in using .htaccess file I have taken windows hosting . here is my code in .htaccess file can you please provide code for .htaccessfile

Comment: Does `www` lead to your server?

Comment: Windows hosting, .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: still website is not being open with www . It is being open with only abc.in